# PHP Session working in WAMP but not in LAMP setup

Tags: php, session

I use session variables to store user details in PHP. I do development under windows7 using WAMP setup and every thing works as programed. When I copy the files to Ubuntu 14.04 server session is not working. After some web search I found that default session.save_path is under /var/lib/php5. But I was not seeing any session files created there. So I set the session.save_path to /tmp in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and created a test.php with just start_session(). This created a session file in /tmp. However when I try to do same in my project I see the error log reporting that variable _SESSION is not defined and also I do not see any session files being created in /tmp.

How do I find what is the problem.

Comment: Always add `session_start()` on top when working with sessions.

Comment: Yes I know. it is working as expected under windows setup. start_session() is the first line in each file where I an using _SESSION variabels.

Comment: Dont add `start_session()` that's not a PHP function. You need to use `session_start()`

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant session_start() indeed. Any idea how do I sort out this problem

Comment: @sknagesh i'm not sure, but can you check the write permission of the session folder ?

Comment: output of ls -ld inside /tmp is drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 12288 Jul  6 17:07 .